# Using GPIO input instead of TDO/DI on the FTDI 2232H Mini-Module

Tags: c++, serial-port, embedded, ftdi

I’m using the FTDI 2232H Mini Module as a module for a system I’m working on. I’m attempting to read data serially from a device using the FTDI’s GPIOs instead of the TDO/DI pin (MPSSE mode). So, for example, my idea of it would be to perhaps connect a GPIO input to the device’s output, and at each SCLK that the FTDI sends, check whether the GPIO input is high or low. By doing this I would be able to store these highs or lows as 1s or 0s, respectively, into a buffer.

Is it possible to do this, or something similar with the FTDI?

Is there a way to keep count of SCLK pulses or rising/falling edges?

I'm using C++ on a Windows environment.

Thanks

Comment: mpsse is basically an instruction set or set of commands to generate waveforms.  then there is bit banged mode where you have to send a command for each stat change.  I assume you are wanting mpsse mode and you "simply" send the right commands to create the waveform you want.

Comment: A PC has nothing that can be used as GPIO nowadays, so it would seem you are out of luck.

Comment: @Lundin - the GPIOs in question are on the FT2232 chip, not the PC.  However, it is likely that bit-banging something with these would be drastically slower if that has to be explicitly done over the USB, rather than having the MPSSE do it locally and only move block data over the USB.  So the question would be if the MPSSE can operate through arbitrary GPIO pins, or only through certain designated pins.  The FT2232 documentation will have the answer.

Comment: Well, that seems needlessly complicated. Why not just use any microcontroller board? Bit of GPIO and USB doesn't exactly sound like mission impossible even with no prior experience of microcontroller programming.

Comment: Right, the GPIOs I'm talking about are on the FTDI chip. The reason I'm trying to use the GPIO pins instead of the Data In pin is because I'm trying to receive input from three different sources, per say, at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is using bit banging which FTDI chips support
including FT232H.
This is the technology I use for my device [Nusbio](http://www.Nusbio.net) and all the bit banging
computation is written in C#.

Here some source executing SPI bit banging to read data from an EEPROM.
[EEPROM/SPI/EEPROM_25AAXXX_BASE.cs](https://github.com/madeintheusb/Nusbio.Samples/blob/master/MadeInTheUSB.Nusbio.Components/EEPROM/SPI/EEPROM_25AAXXX_BASE.cs)

Bit banging is good for chip like the FT232RL or FT231X.
But if you have an FT232H, you can do better.

To answer you question the key is know what is the communication
protocol used by the device your are trying to read data from.

If the protocol is SPI, I2C, JTAG or Serial Port then you should use the native
mode supported by the FT232H.
As mentioned it is called mpsse, Multi-Protocol Synchronous Serial Engine
to simplify synchronous serial protocol (USB to JTAG, I2C, SPI (MASTER) or bit-bang)
design.

If your device support some exoteric protocol with a CLOCK wire which you mentioned, you might have to write your own bit banging.

> Is there a way to keep count of SCLK pulses or rising/falling edges?
>   The Windows PC moslt likely would considered the master so your program is in charge of clocking HIGH and LOW and keeping track of it.

[I2C Bit banging Adafruit 16x9 LED Matrix with Nusbio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31QBlvzhxS0)

[mpsse SPI with the FT232H and OLED 128x64 display](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i8_EFs_j0I)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured this out a while ago. It was actually quite simple. 

The device used SPI to output data in parallel from different pins at each positive clock edge. I had each of these pins connected to a GPIO (set as input) on the FTDI. All I needed to do was send the FTDI the command to toggle the pin representing the serial clock (which was also the serial clock for the SPI device), extract the status of the FTDI input pins, parse them, and repeat until the full amount of data bits were extracted.

So as you said, bit bang them.